# Is it possible to get as good inpainting as with RGB having only grayscale image?

Tags: image-processing

The question derived from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112361/why-is-inpainting-worse-in-grayscale-than-in-rgb-image). According to the [answer by nikie](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112882/21532), for grayscale image with `Method->"TextureSynthesis"` we get much worse result than for RGB image because the latter contains additional information used by `Method->"TextureSynthesis"`. Is it still possible to get as good inpainting(without that something like a blob) as with RGB having only grayscale image?And we need not to use `Inpaint` strictly,just for a better effect.

```
img = Import /@ {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/klqh9.png", 
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCjXN.png"};
mask = Dilation[Binarize[First@img, {0, .15}], 2];
result = Prepend[
  Inpaint[#, mask, Method -> "TextureSynthesis"] & /@ img, First@img]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @YvesKlett If you know what I mean,help me improve it please.

Comment: Sorry, I was just joking on inpainted vs inpained - already corrected ;-)

Comment: @yode I improved your question and the title. For the future: please spend more time on making a **good**, well-formulated question! It looks like you spend on writing of each of your questions only about half a minute but even with fluent English it is insufficient time for writing a *good* question.

Comment: @yode Actually even with my improvements the question still contains insufficient information and requires significant efforts from a reader in order to guess what are you asking for. Probably you should add more information about your actual goals: from where the images are obtained, what is the meaning of the black blobs you wish to remove, why in some situations you have access only to grayscale versions.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Ok,thanks for your reminder.